# Changing font size of the signature of an outlook email generated through VBA

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

i'm able to make the signature bold but i cant change the size. I can also change the size of the body but not the signature. I need to change the font size of the signature to match the font size of the body in the email.

```
Sub Email_Test()

'Exit function if user input incomplete:
If IsNull(Forms!frmCompMain!cboPayPrd) = True Then
            MsgBox "Please provide the Pay Period parameter!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
            End If

'-----------------------------------------
----'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES


 Dim myOutlok As Object
    Dim myMailItm As Object
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim OtlApp As Object
    Dim OtlNewMail As Object
    Dim olMailItem As Object
    Dim PayPrd As String


    Set OtlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OtlNewMail = OtlApp.CreateItem(0)


    PayPrd = Forms!frmCompMain!cboPayPrd
'-----------------------------------------
-----'GET DEFAULT EMAIL SIGNATURE


Signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(Signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        Signature = Signature & Dir$(Signature & "*.htm")
    Else:
        Signature = ""
    End If
    Signature = 



CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(Signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

'-----------------------------------------
----'CREATE EMAIL


OtlNewMail.HTMLBody = Signature
    With OtlNewMail
    .to = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = "<font size='2'> Hello," & "<br />" & _
    "<br />" & _
    "" & "<br />" & _
    "<br />" & _
    "<b>Production Period:</b> " & DateSerial(Year(PayPrd)" & _
    "<br />" & _
    "<b> Pay Date:</b> " & DateSerial(Year(PayPrd), Month(PayPrd) + 1, 10) & 
    "<br />" & _
    "<br />" & _
    "Please let me know if you have any questions." & "<br />" & _
    "<br />" & _
    "<b>" & Signature & "</b>"
    .display
    '.Send
    End With
'-----------------------------------------
----'CLEANUP


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML string back. The two must be merged.

Secondly, if the font size is explicitly set in the HTML signature, your code explicitly wrapping the signature in an element with a specified font size would do nothing. You'd need to use the HTMLDocument interface or the Word object model to set the size.

Or, the simplest possible solution, make sure the stationary signature already has the right font.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code replace the .HTMLBody content:

```
Signature = "<b style='color:red;'>Your Sigature</b>"    
With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = "<font style='font-size:20px !important;'> Hello <br /><br/><br/><b>Production Period:</b> DateSerial(Year(PayPrd)<br /><b> Pay Date:</b>  DateSerial(Year(PayPrd), Month(PayPrd) + 1, 10)<br/><br/>Please let me know if you have any questions.<br/><br/><b style='font-size 14px !important'>" & Signature & "</b></font>"
        .Display
```

If the font size is set in the HTML signature, You'd need to use the HTMLDocument interface to set the size.